# GeoServer - Multiple symbology on single layer

Tags: geoserver, symbology, sld, geoserver-css-module

I'm trying to show multiple symbologies on a single GeoServer layer.
I'm also using the CSS extension, but an SLD example would be fine.

My GeoServer version is 2.8.2

For example:
A yellow rectangle with a red circle within it(on a point layer).

[image]

Is there a way for me to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in the [documentation](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/extensions/css/styledmarks.html#example-styled-symbol) this is achieved by applying two (or more) marks to the point. So for your example something like:

```
[usage='example'] {
  mark: symbol('square'), symbol('circle');
}

[usage='example'] :nth-mark(1) {
  size: 16px;
  fill: yellow;
}

[usage='example'] :nth-mark(2) {
  size: 14px;
  fill: red;
}
```